# how to recup solana sent by mistake to metamask address?

Tags: sol

I sent by mistake sol to my metamask address in solana chain,
I didn't use raydium to make my wallet
how can I recupe that ?

Comment: Was it solana or wrapped solana? If solana, Metamask does not support solana addresses, so high chances that u have lost the solana. If wrapped solana, then u must figure out on which blockchain the wsol exists and then u can retrieve it